# Random Word List Issue

Tags: python

Alright so far I have created a list containing a long list of words each on it's own line... I'm wanting to pick a random word only once and then also print to the screen with a little extra information saying, "Define: (and then the word it picked random)". Anyways when I run the below code I only get the define text only once and thats at the beginning of the run time, as I mentioned above I want it on every line it prints..

```
words = ['''
word1
word2
word3
''']

while len(words) > 0:
     word = "Define:"+random.choice(words)
     print word
     words.remove(word)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
words = [
'word1',
'word2',
'word3',
]

while len(words) > 0:
     word = random.choice(words)
     print "Define: %s" % word
     words.remove(word)
```

This little change might help :). Also I strongly advice to print strings like done above

Comment: This didn't help, I just ran it and the same thing happened.

Comment: Oh lol sorry, I see now you're adding the words quoting them only once. I'll edit what it should be :) I.e. every word needs quotes around it instead of just a new line. Also they need to be separated by comma's.

Comment: Yes, but I have several thouands that should be changed not just a few, that's why I was using the other method. Is their a built in Python dictionary I can do this from?

Comment: What format is your dictionary? How do you add them to the code? **Edit**: a solution is given: use splitlines :)

Answer (score 2):

Words needs to be an actual list

```
#Wrong
words = ['''
word1
word2
word3
''']
#Better
words = ['word1','word2','word3']
```

You only get the prompt once because you're using a list of length 1.

Comment: I would use the list command properly but I'm using a single word per line dictionary and It would take forever to place each and every one of these in quotations. Any other ideas?

Comment: Better: words = wordstr.splitlines() -- will handle line endings from different platforms cleanly

Comment: Alternatively: Have your words in a separate file, then open the file, and `words = wordsfile.readlines()`

Answer (score 1):

The error lies here:

```
words = ['''
word1
word2
word3
''']
```

This is a list with just one element (a long string), not a list of words. Do this instead

```
words = '''
word1
word2
word3
'''.splitlines()
```

You can make the rest a big more straight forward too. Since you want to print all the words in random order, you might as well just shuffle the list:

```
random.shuffle(words)
for word in words:
    print "Define:", word
```

Comment: Are you using python >= 3.0?  if so you need to change `print "Define:", word` into `print("Define: "+word)`

Comment: No, I'm using Python 3.2 and I've tried adding a plus instead... same error.

Answer (score 1):

`wordlist=words.split('\n')` will convert it into a list.

Answer (score 0):

The main problems in your code are that `words` is not a list, but rather a single multi-line string. The other issue was you're setting `word` to `'Define'+random word` which of course is something `remove()` isn't going to find in the list. Here's a version that addresses both those issues:

```
import random

words = '''
    word1
    word2
    word3
'''

# remove any excess whitespace from words string and convert it to a list
words = [line.strip() for line in words.strip().split('\n')]
print words
# ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']

while len(words) > 0:
     word = random.choice(words)
     print "Define:", word
     words.remove(word)
# Define: word1
# Define: word3
# Define: word2
```